# Hashmap of Jsoup output

Tags: android, hashmap, jsoup

I have a html file which looks like:

```
<html>
<body>
<h3>title 1</h3>
<a>'a paragraph here'</a>
<a>'a paragraph here'</a>
<a>'a paragraph here'</a>
<h3><b>title 2</b></h3>
<a>'a paragraph here'</a>
<a>'a paragraph here'</a>
<a>'a paragraph here'</a>
</body></html>
```

Problem: Hashmap store all `<a>` tag under both title 1 and title 2. Whereas I want to store each `<h3>` tag as key and the following `<a>` tags as its value.

Secondly the stored output I get includes tags like `<h3>`,`<b>` and `<br>`. Where can I implement `Html.frmHtml` in this code to get a proper formatted output.

```
public HashMap<String, List<String>> CreateMas() throws IOException{
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
String name = "1.html";
InputStream is = getAssets().open(name);
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(is, "UTF-8", "http");
HashMap<String, List<String>> mas = new HashMap<String, List<String>>(); 

for( Element element : doc.select("h3") )
{
    String main = element.toString();
       \\Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), main, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    for( Element elemen : doc.select("a") )
    {   List<String> subm = new ArrayList<String>();        
        String sub = elemen.toString();
        subm.add(sub);
        mas.put(main,subm);
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by proper formatted output? And what does  `Html.frmHtml` do in that context? Please formulate clearly what you expect as a result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand what you mean by proper formatted output, but I think at least I can help you with the first part of your question. That is how to build a map with the h3 tag texts as keys and the following a tags in a list as values:

```
String html = ""
    +"<html>"
    +"<body>"
    +"<h3>title 1</h3>"
    +"<a>'a paragraph 1 here'</a>"
    +"<a>'a paragraph 2 here'</a>"
    +"<a>'a paragraph 3 here'</a>"
    +"<h3><b>title 2</b></h3>"
    +"<a>'a paragraph 4 here'</a>"
    +"<a>'a paragraph 5 here'</a>"
    +"<a>'a paragraph 6 here'</a>"
    +"</body></html>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

Elements as = doc.select("a");
String currentTitle = null;
Map<String,List<String>> mas = new LinkedHashMap<>();
for (Element a : as){
    if ("h3".equals(a.previousElementSibling().tagName())){
        currentTitle = a.previousElementSibling().text();
        mas.put(currentTitle, new ArrayList<String>());
    }
    mas.get(currentTitle).add(a.text());
}

System.out.println(""+mas);
```

The program above uses the `previousElementSibling()` method to identify the h3 tag if it is directly before an a element. The rest should be easy to understand.

Note that I use a LinkedHashMap in order to the original order of the h3 tags.

Comment: @lukschThanks for the reply it made my day.